# "Expression cannot be assigned at line X" - Trying to incrementally increase quantity of Decimal value in an <Id,Decimal> map in a for() loop

Tags: apex, map, loop, decimal

> **Scenario:** We have a quoting system with a child object called
>   `zqu__QuoteCharge__c` that acts as the individual line items on the
>   quote. `zqu__QuoteCharge__c` is also the child of
>   `zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c`, which holds a total available quantity
>   field that comes from another connected app.
>
> I recently created a class that just acts as a sophisticated, dynamic
>   validation rule that makes sure the amount you are trying to sell
>   doesn't exceed the total available quantity. If it does, we .addError
>   in the loop so that the VR inserts the name of the product, available
>   quantity, and quantity that you are trying to sell.

---

> **Problem:** Users in our org have the potential to add the same item as
>   2+ lines (2+ `zqu__QuoteCharge__c` records) if they are discounting one
>   of the products but not the other, etc. To deal with this, I've
>   attempted to create an `<Id,Decimal>` map that, while in the for loop
>   through new QuoteCharge records, puts `<Id,0>` if the key isn't already
>   found, and if the key is found I instead try to increment the number
>   by getting the current value for that key and then adding (`+=`) the
>   quantity of the record in the loop. The line of code that
>   should be incrementing the value is where the error occurs.

---

I've added my code below, and added `!!!ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!` to the comment on the line that throws the error in my compiler.

**Code:**

```
public void customValidation(List<zqu__QuoteCharge__c> newList){
    if (newList != null && newList.size() > 0){

        Map<Id,zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c> rpcMap = new Map<Id,zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c>(); // Create a map for ProductRatePlanCharge (parent object) where the total available quantity is held 
        Map<Id, Decimal> parentToQuantity = new Map<Id, Decimal>(); // Create a map to count the total quantity related to the same parent

        for(zqu__QuoteCharge__c quoteCharge : newList){
            if(quoteCharge.Name != 'Discount'){ // skip discount records as they do not apply for available quantity checks
                if(!parentToQuantity.containsKey(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c)){ // if key doesn't already exist
                    parentToQuantity.put(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c,0); // put key with default count of 0
                }
                else{ // if key already exists
                    parentToQuantity.put(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c,parentToQuantity.get(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c) += quoteCharge.zqu__Quantity__c); // !!!ERROR OCCURS HERE!!! update key/val pair, current val += quantity of charge
                }
                rpcMap.put(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c,null); // put the ProductRatePlanCharge in the map to later check available quantity
            }
        }

        // Debug
        System.debug('parentToQuantity KeySet::: ' +parentToQuantity.keySet());
        System.debug('parentToQuantity Total Values::: ' +parentToQuantity.values());

        rpcMap.remove(null); // remove null key      
        rpcMap.putAll([SELECT Id, Name, Ascent_Quantity__c FROM zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c WHERE Id IN :rpcMap.keySet()]); // build real map of ProductRatePlanCharge (parent object) from keySet

        for(zqu__QuoteCharge__c quoteCharge : newList){
            if(quoteCharge.Name != 'Discount'){ // Skip discount records as they do not apply for available quantity checks
                if(rpcMap.containsKey(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c)){ // if this quote charge is the child of a PRPC in our rpcMap
                    Decimal ascentQuantity = rpcMap.get(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c).Ascent_Quantity__c; // create friendlier Decimal val for available quantity from ascent
                    Decimal productQuantity = parentToQuantity.get(quoteCharge.zqu__ProductRatePlanCharge__c); // create friendlier Decimal val for total quantity being inserted

                    // Debug
                    System.debug('Ascent Quantity:: ' +ascentQuantity);
                    System.debug('Product Quantity:: ' +productQuantity);

                    if(ascentQuantity == 0 || ascentQuantity < productQuantity){
                            /*Add to the productMap to stop a recursive update attempt from the linkDiscountsToCharges method
                            // the productMap is a private class scope map where we put the quoteCharges when they fail to meet the VR criteria.
                            // We do this because we need to check later to see if they are in the map before trying to update the associated discount record.
                            // Since the discount is its own separate record which tries to update itself whenever you update the related product, even if it wasn't changed (thanks Zuora -_-)
                            // this should stop us from attempting to save any new discounts to the records if the product itself wasn't committed to DB due to failing VR criteria
                            // but should still allow us to adjust the discount % on updates if they don't fail the VR */
                            productMap.put(quoteCharge.Id,quoteCharge);
                            // VALIDATION ERROR USING quoteCharge.addError();
                            quoteCharge.addError('The Product "' +quoteCharge.Name + '" only has ' +ascentQuantity + ' in stock but you are trying to sell ' +productQuantity);
                            //Old
                            //quoteCharge.addError('The Product "' +quoteCharge.Name + '" only has ' +ascentQuantity + ' in stock but you are trying to sell ' +quoteCharge.zqu__Quantity__c.intValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is reproducible using execute anonymous. This does not compile with the error:

```
Decimal x = (1 += 2);
```

and this does:

```
Decimal x = (1 + 2);
```

While you perhaps can argue that the `+=` should work, the `+` is the more appropriate operator in this case.

Or to use the map idiom from the question this does not compile:

```
m.put(key, m.get(key) += increment);
```

and this does:

```
m.put(key, m.get(key) + increment);
```

Comment: Hahahaha... wow. Literally one keystroke. I've been ONE = sign away from going home for the last hour! Thank you!